# Using file and loop in c

Tags: c, loops, file

*In this program, how i do at the same time convert the uppercase letters  to lowercase letters and lowercase letters to uppercase letter?*

*I have tried many times but it is not working.*

**My expectations, Suppose for example**

**Input:**

```
 from read.txt(orginal contant of the file:
 Hello World)
```

**Output**

```
hELLO wORLD
```

**This is my code....
(I can only convert from uppercase to lowercase. At the same time I could not convert from uppercase to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase).**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() 
{ 

    FILE* file;
    char ch;  

    file = fopen("read.txt","r"); 

    while (ch != EOF) 
    { 
        ch = toupper(ch); 

        printf("%c", ch); 

        ch = fgetc(file); 
    }  
    fclose(file);
    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: You should read the character somewhere *before* doing tests on it.

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. What *is* it doing?

Comment: you did not even compile it. Is it too complicated to remember the variable name in the 6 lines program?

Answer (score 1):

you have plenty errors here.

your first check the not initialized `ch` variable, you use it and try to print, then you read it. The order has to be right opposite.

`ch` has to be of type `int` to accommodate EOF

you need to check if the `fopen` was successful

```
int main() 
{ 
    FILE* fptr;
    int ch;  

    fptr = fopen("read.txt","r"); 

    if(fptr)
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) 
        { 
            ch = toupper(ch); 
            printf("%c", ch); 
        }  
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What's `fptr`? Not defined here. Meaning `file`?

Comment: Oh I get that, it's just another mistake that needs patching. Not your bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Note that UPPER and lower chars differ by bit 5 (value 0x20).
// If you want to switch case for any [A-Za-z] in one step,
// an exclusive-OR (^ bitwise operator) can be used:

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TOGGLE_CASE(c)  ((c) ^ 0x20)

int
main(void)
{ 
    FILE *file;
    char ch;  

    if ((file = fopen("read.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        dprintf(2, "fopen error\n");
        return (1);
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", isalpha(ch) ? TOGGLE_CASE(ch) : ch);
    fclose(file);

    return (0); 
}
```